# Video Url Resolver for dailymotion and blip.tv

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I'm stuck in getting the direct link of the video file on dailymotion and blip.tv website.
Ex:
direct video url of http: //www.dailymotion.com/video/x96bku_the-forest-short-animation-film_shortfilms is http: //proxy-36.dailymotion.com/video/684/114/15411486%3amp4_h264_aac_hq.mp4?auth=1281348558-2a834e9c8537ef9c8301dcae7c5c565a

http: //blip.tv/file/2765938/ -> http: //a52.video2.blip.tv/7320004900441/BenjaminHershleder-PixarOpeningParody552.flv
These links are captured by IDM

I appreciate any idea that could help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [Embedly](http://embed.ly/)?  It allows you to give the url of a resource and receive the embed code for that resource.

While it might not give you the url directly, it will at least give you a structured format (the HTML) which you can then parse to try and get the video file data you need.